# Which folder properties are inherited

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For our project we have certain svn properties that should be applied to all folders in the repo. For instance the `bugtraq:xxx`, and the `svn:ignore` properties.

And when creating and adding a new folder to the repo the `bugtraq:xxx` properties are applied to the new folder, but the `svn:ignore` are not...

Why?

**Edit**
So I'm adding a tree example:

```
[Root]
   |-- Admin [no props]
   |-- Software [no props]
         |-- MySoftwareProject [B (=Bugtraq)]
               |-- tags [B]
               |-- branches [B]
               |-- trunk [B]
                     |-- Folder_A [B & I (=Ignore)]
                     |-- Folder_B [B & I]
                           |-- New_Folder_C [B]
```

Ok, so when I create & add the `New_Folder_C` it automatically gets `Bugtraq` but not `svn:ignore`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## New for Subversion 1.8 Client

There's are two new standard properties in Subversion 1.8 clients:

- `svn:global-ignores`
- `svn:auto-props`

These properties are *inheritable*. That is, when you set one of these properties on a parent directory, it applies to all sub-directories too. This allows you to create a new way of setting auto properties and project wide global-ignores.

This will take care of your problem. However, you must make sure that everyone is using the latest version of TortoiseSVN in order to take advantage of this.

I also recommend you use my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) which can enforce the use of properties on files and directories. This hook will reject comments unless the properties are correctly set on all files added or modified in the commit.

Answer (score 3):

In Subversion, properties are never inherited. You can click the "Apply property recursively" checkbox when setting properties and TortoiseSVN will automatically make a copy of the property on each descending folder, but it's just a time-saving feature your Subversion client offers.

The `bugtraq:` property family is a [custom feature implemented by the TortoiseSVN and Subclipse development teams](http://markphip.blogspot.com.es/2007/01/integrating-subversion-with-your-issue.html). What happens is that TortoiseSVN uses the bugtracker feature as soon as it finds the given tags in the root folder of your working copy—there's no need to have the property on every folder.

It isn't the case with `svn:ignore` because its a standard Subversion property and that's how it's been designed to behave.

Comment: Ahaa so you mean that the `bugtraq` properties also belongs to the `tsvn` properties. And that it is Tortoise that adds them when I add a folder, as long as the exist in a parent folder?

Comment: @Markus - I've edited the question because I mistyped the property name. But I should clarify that I was assuming that the property was not actually on the subfolder's "Properties" dialogue. If my assumption is wrong, Larry's answer is probably the correct explanation.

Comment: So I updated my question, to make it more clear what I mean. I'd say your answer seems more likely than Larry's, but that's because I haven't seen any `tsvn` anywhere, and the `autoprops` is disabled.

Comment: @Markus - If you right click on `New_Folder_C` and go to *TortoiseSVN/ Properties*, can you see `bugtraq:...` there?

Comment: @Markus - Then you must have an `[auto-props]` section somewhere in your Subversion configuration that adds `bugtraq:...`, as Larry explains. My answer does not apply.

Comment: As of svn 1.8 properties are inheritable:
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#iprops

Comment: @whitey04 Well, not really ;-)

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is probably using a SVN feature called [auto props](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto). You can also see about them [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) in the TortoiseSVN documentation, since there are also special `tsvn:autoprops` as well.

Comment: It's strange, I don't see the tsvn:autoprops in any of the folders that I can "reach". And it seems that the `bugtraq` only exists from a certain level in our repo... (just in top of the `Software/{ttb}`). Might be that is't some hooking magic somewhere... I'm gonna wait a bit to see if anyone else has any other solution. Good link though.

Comment: @Markus - Please look for `[auto-props]` and `bugtraq:` (*not* `tsvn:autoprop`) inside `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`. Auto props is *not* a TortoiseSVN feature, it's a Subversion feature.